# Making UILabels activate UITextfields

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uitextfield, uilabel

I'm new to objective C and currently working on a small project.  I have an IB set up with a login screen.  Inside that login screen I have labels (display name, email, password) next to my UITextfields.  My question here, is how do I get people who tap on the labels to activate the textfields?  So far I've created outlets for my labels, but I'm stuck on the method that I need to implement.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option is to create a button with the type "Custom" (it will be transparent) and put it on top of the label.

Then, you detect that the button has been pressed, and you activate the textfields!

Comment: I wondered if that would be easier, and thanks very much for the reply, but how do I get those buttons to actually activate the textfields?

Comment: Send the textfield a becomeFirstResponder message.  So in the method that is called by TouchUpInside something like [self.textField becomeFirstResponder];